# same playbook between jenkins and ansible server doesn't work

Tags: jenkins, ansible

I try to manage my Ansible server with Jenkins job and I observe two differents results for two similars actions.

**This is my playbook :**

---

```
- hosts: lpdepmld2
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - shell: whoami; hostname; pwd
    register: test

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ test.stdout_lines }}"
```

**Locally on Ansible serveur, I execute :**

```
cd /etc/ansible
whoami; hostname; pwd
ansible-playbook /etc/ansible/playbooks/test.yml --private-key /home/ansible/.ssh/id_rsa -u ansible -vvv
```

**And it works as expected, result :**

```
root
lpansmld1
/etc/ansible

ansible-playbook 2.8.4
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/etc/ansible/library']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /bin/ansible-playbook
  python version = 2.7.5 (default, Jun 11 2019, 14:33:56) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)]
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
host_list declined parsing /etc/ansible/hosts as it did not pass it's verify_file() method
auto declined parsing /etc/ansible/hosts as it did not pass it's verify_file() method
 [WARNING]: Invalid characters were found in group names but not replaced, use -vvvv to see details

Parsed /etc/ansible/hosts inventory source with ini plugin

PLAYBOOK: test.yml **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
1 plays in /etc/ansible/playbooks/test.yml

PLAY [lpdepmld2] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
META: ran handlers

TASK [shell] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /etc/ansible/playbooks/test.yml:6
Tuesday 29 December 2020  16:35:05 +0100 (0:00:00.111)       0:00:00.112 ******
<lpdepmld2.uem.lan> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: ansible
<lpdepmld2.uem.lan> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o 'IdentityFile="/home/ansible/.ssh/id_rsa"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="ansible"' -o ConnectTimeout=60 -o ControlPath=/root/.ansible/cp/a35139d2ee lpdepmld2.uem.lan '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo ~ansible && sleep 0'"'"''
<lpdepmld2.uem.lan> (0, '/home/ansible\n', '')
<lpdepmld2.uem.lan> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: ansible
<lpdepmld2.uem.lan> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o 'IdentityFile="/home/ansible/.ssh/id_rsa"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="ansible"' -o ConnectTimeout=60 -o ControlPath=/root/.ansible/cp/a35139d2ee lpdepmld2.uem.lan '/bin/sh -c '"'"'( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1609256105.11-16196748238057 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1609256105.11-16196748238057="` echo /home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1609256105.11-16196748238057 `" ) && sleep 0'"'"''
<lpdepmld2.uem.lan> (0, 'ansible-tmp-1609256105.11-16196748238057=/home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1609256105.11-16196748238057\n', '')
<lpdepmld2> Attempting python interpreter discovery
<lpdepmld2.uem.lan> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: ansible
<lpdepmld2.uem.lan> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o 'IdentityFile="/home/ansible/.ssh/id_rsa"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="ansible"' -o ConnectTimeout=60 -o ControlPath=/root/.ansible/cp/a35139d2ee lpdepmld2.uem.lan '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo PLATFORM; uname; echo FOUND; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'/usr/bin/python'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'python3.7'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'python3.6'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'python3.5'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'python2.7'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'python2.6'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'/usr/libexec/platform-python'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'/usr/bin/python3'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'python'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; echo ENDFOUND && sleep 0'"'"''
<lpdepmld2.uem.lan> (0, 'PLATFORM\nLinux\nFOUND\n/usr/bin/python\n/usr/bin/python2.7\n/usr/bin/python\nENDFOUND\n', '')
<lpdepmld2.uem.lan> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: ansible
<lpdepmld2.uem.lan> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o 'IdentityFile="/home/ansible/.ssh/id_rsa"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="ansible"' -o ConnectTimeout=60 -o ControlPath=/root/.ansible/cp/a35139d2ee lpdepmld2.uem.lan '/bin/sh -c '"'"'/usr/bin/python && sleep 0'"'"''
<lpdepmld2.uem.lan> (0, '{"osrelease_content": "NAME=\\"Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server\\"\\nVERSION=\\"7.5 (Maipo)\\"\\nID=\\"rhel\\"\\nID_LIKE=\\"fedora\\"\\nVARIANT=\\"Server\\"\\nVARIANT_ID=\\"server\\"\\nVERSION_ID=\\"7.5\\"\\nPRETTY_NAME=\\"Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.5 (Maipo)\\"\\nANSI_COLOR=\\"0;31\\"\\nCPE_NAME=\\"cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:7.5:GA:server\\"\\nHOME_URL=\\"https://www.redhat.com/\\"\\nBUG_REPORT_URL=\\"https://bugzilla.redhat.com/\\"\\n\\nREDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT=\\"Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7\\"\\nREDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=7.5\\nREDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT=\\"Red Hat Enterprise Linux\\"\\nREDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION=\\"7.5\\"\\n", "platform_dist_result": ["redhat", "7.5", "Maipo"]}\n', '')
Using module file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/commands/command.py
<lpdepmld2.uem.lan> PUT /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-102513iMMnYg/tmpzX9hsf TO /home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1609256105.11-16196748238057/AnsiballZ_command.py
<lpdepmld2.uem.lan> SSH: EXEC sftp -b - -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o 'IdentityFile="/home/ansible/.ssh/id_rsa"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="ansible"' -o ConnectTimeout=60 -o ControlPath=/root/.ansible/cp/a35139d2ee '[lpdepmld2.uem.lan]'
<lpdepmld2.uem.lan> (0, 'sftp> put /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-102513iMMnYg/tmpzX9hsf /home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1609256105.11-16196748238057/AnsiballZ_command.py\n', '')
<lpdepmld2.uem.lan> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: ansible
<lpdepmld2.uem.lan> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o 'IdentityFile="/home/ansible/.ssh/id_rsa"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="ansible"' -o ConnectTimeout=60 -o ControlPath=/root/.ansible/cp/a35139d2ee lpdepmld2.uem.lan '/bin/sh -c '"'"'chmod u+x /home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1609256105.11-16196748238057/ /home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1609256105.11-16196748238057/AnsiballZ_command.py && sleep 0'"'"''
<lpdepmld2.uem.lan> (0, '', '')
<lpdepmld2.uem.lan> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: ansible
<lpdepmld2.uem.lan> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o 'IdentityFile="/home/ansible/.ssh/id_rsa"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="ansible"' -o ConnectTimeout=60 -o ControlPath=/root/.ansible/cp/a35139d2ee -tt lpdepmld2.uem.lan '/bin/sh -c '"'"'/usr/bin/python /home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1609256105.11-16196748238057/AnsiballZ_command.py && sleep 0'"'"''
<lpdepmld2.uem.lan> (0, '\r\n{"changed": true, "end": "2020-12-29 16:35:06.054473", "stdout": "ansible\\nlpdepmld2\\n/home/ansible", "cmd": "whoami; hostname; pwd", "rc": 0, "start": "2020-12-29 16:35:06.047227", "stderr": "", "delta": "0:00:00.007246", "invocation": {"module_args": {"creates": null, "executable": null, "_uses_shell": true, "strip_empty_ends": true, "_raw_params": "whoami; hostname; pwd", "removes": null, "argv": null, "warn": true, "chdir": null, "stdin_add_newline": true, "stdin": null}}}\r\n', 'Shared connection to lpdepmld2.uem.lan closed.\r\n')
<lpdepmld2.uem.lan> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: ansible
<lpdepmld2.uem.lan> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o 'IdentityFile="/home/ansible/.ssh/id_rsa"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="ansible"' -o ConnectTimeout=60 -o ControlPath=/root/.ansible/cp/a35139d2ee lpdepmld2.uem.lan '/bin/sh -c '"'"'rm -f -r /home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1609256105.11-16196748238057/ > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'"'"''
<lpdepmld2.uem.lan> (0, '', '')
changed: [lpdepmld2] => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"
    },
    "changed": true,
    "cmd": "whoami; hostname; pwd",
    "delta": "0:00:00.007246",
    "end": "2020-12-29 16:35:06.054473",
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "_raw_params": "whoami; hostname; pwd",
            "_uses_shell": true,
            "argv": null,
            "chdir": null,
            "creates": null,
            "executable": null,
            "removes": null,
            "stdin": null,
            "stdin_add_newline": true,
            "strip_empty_ends": true,
            "warn": true
        }
    },
    "rc": 0,
    "start": "2020-12-29 16:35:06.047227",
    "stderr": "",
    "stderr_lines": [],
    "stdout": "ansible\nlpdepmld2\n/home/ansible",
    "stdout_lines": [
        "ansible",
        "lpdepmld2",
        "/home/ansible"
    ]
}

TASK [debug] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /etc/ansible/playbooks/test.yml:9
Tuesday 29 December 2020  16:35:06 +0100 (0:00:01.067)       0:00:01.179 ******
ok: [lpdepmld2] => {
    "msg": [
        "ansible",
        "lpdepmld2",
        "/home/ansible"
    ]
}
META: ran handlers
META: ran handlers

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
lpdepmld2                  : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0

Tuesday 29 December 2020  16:35:06 +0100 (0:00:00.034)       0:00:01.214 ******
===============================================================================
shell ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 1.07s
/etc/ansible/playbooks/test.yml:6 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
debug ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 0.04s
/etc/ansible/playbooks/test.yml:9 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Playbook run took 0 days, 0 hours, 0 minutes, 1 seconds
```

And the `/var/log/secure` log on remote server at this moment :

```
Dec 29 16:35:05 lpdepmld2 sshd[61126]: Accepted publickey for ansible from 192.168.210.101 port 55946 ssh2: RSA SHA256:iZKO/9tfS6am2YAk8JRKDalRRwDNDubC5FAm+UUA9qw
Dec 29 16:35:05 lpdepmld2 sshd[61126]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user ansible by (uid=0)
```

**So now, i'm doing the same thing with Jenkins, through this job :**

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /etc/ansible

whoami; hostname; pwd

ansible-playbook /etc/ansible/playbooks/test.yml --private-key /home/ansible/.ssh/id_rsa -u ansible -vvv
```

**The Jenkins result :**

```
Started by user adminlocal
Running as SYSTEM
Building remotely on lpansmld1 in workspace /data/jenkins_agent/workspace/test/test
[test] $ /bin/bash /tmp/jenkins1557636937643197894.sh
root
lpansmld1
/etc/ansible
ansible-playbook 2.8.4
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/etc/ansible/library']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible-playbook
  python version = 2.7.5 (default, Jun 11 2019, 14:33:56) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)]
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
host_list declined parsing /etc/ansible/hosts as it did not pass it's verify_file() method
auto declined parsing /etc/ansible/hosts as it did not pass it's verify_file() method
 [WARNING]: Invalid characters were found in group names but not replaced, use
-vvvv to see details
Parsed /etc/ansible/hosts inventory source with ini plugin

PLAYBOOK: test.yml *************************************************************
1 plays in /etc/ansible/playbooks/test.yml

PLAY [lpdepmld2] ***************************************************************
META: ran handlers

TASK [shell] *******************************************************************
task path: /etc/ansible/playbooks/test.yml:6
Tuesday 29 December 2020  16:38:53 +0100 (0:00:00.106)       0:00:00.106 ****** 
<lpdepmld2.uem.lan> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: ansible
<lpdepmld2.uem.lan> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o 'IdentityFile="/home/ansible/.ssh/id_rsa"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="ansible"' -o ConnectTimeout=60 -o ControlPath=/root/.ansible/cp/a35139d2ee lpdepmld2.uem.lan '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo ~ansible && sleep 0'"'"''
<lpdepmld2.uem.lan> (0, '/home/ansible\n', '')
<lpdepmld2.uem.lan> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: ansible
<lpdepmld2.uem.lan> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o 'IdentityFile="/home/ansible/.ssh/id_rsa"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="ansible"' -o ConnectTimeout=60 -o ControlPath=/root/.ansible/cp/a35139d2ee lpdepmld2.uem.lan '/bin/sh -c '"'"'( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1609256333.17-248021594072394 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1609256333.17-248021594072394="` echo /home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1609256333.17-248021594072394 `" ) && sleep 0'"'"''
<lpdepmld2.uem.lan> (0, 'ansible-tmp-1609256333.17-248021594072394=/home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1609256333.17-248021594072394\n', '')
<lpdepmld2> Attempting python interpreter discovery
<lpdepmld2.uem.lan> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: ansible
<lpdepmld2.uem.lan> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o 'IdentityFile="/home/ansible/.ssh/id_rsa"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="ansible"' -o ConnectTimeout=60 -o ControlPath=/root/.ansible/cp/a35139d2ee lpdepmld2.uem.lan '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo PLATFORM; uname; echo FOUND; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'/usr/bin/python'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'python3.7'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'python3.6'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'python3.5'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'python2.7'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'python2.6'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'/usr/libexec/platform-python'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'/usr/bin/python3'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'python'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; echo ENDFOUND && sleep 0'"'"''
<lpdepmld2.uem.lan> (0, 'PLATFORM\nLinux\nFOUND\n/usr/bin/python\n/usr/bin/python2.7\n/usr/bin/python\nENDFOUND\n', '')
<lpdepmld2.uem.lan> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: ansible
<lpdepmld2.uem.lan> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o 'IdentityFile="/home/ansible/.ssh/id_rsa"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="ansible"' -o ConnectTimeout=60 -o ControlPath=/root/.ansible/cp/a35139d2ee lpdepmld2.uem.lan '/bin/sh -c '"'"'/usr/bin/python && sleep 0'"'"''
<lpdepmld2.uem.lan> (0, '{"osrelease_content": "NAME=\\"Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server\\"\\nVERSION=\\"7.5 (Maipo)\\"\\nID=\\"rhel\\"\\nID_LIKE=\\"fedora\\"\\nVARIANT=\\"Server\\"\\nVARIANT_ID=\\"server\\"\\nVERSION_ID=\\"7.5\\"\\nPRETTY_NAME=\\"Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.5 (Maipo)\\"\\nANSI_COLOR=\\"0;31\\"\\nCPE_NAME=\\"cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:7.5:GA:server\\"\\nHOME_URL=\\"https://www.redhat.com/\\"\\nBUG_REPORT_URL=\\"https://bugzilla.redhat.com/\\"\\n\\nREDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT=\\"Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7\\"\\nREDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=7.5\\nREDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT=\\"Red Hat Enterprise Linux\\"\\nREDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION=\\"7.5\\"\\n", "platform_dist_result": ["redhat", "7.5", "Maipo"]}\n', '')
Using module file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/commands/command.py
<lpdepmld2.uem.lan> PUT /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-105179U75Grh/tmp7Lwygf TO /home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1609256333.17-248021594072394/AnsiballZ_command.py
<lpdepmld2.uem.lan> SSH: EXEC sftp -b - -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o 'IdentityFile="/home/ansible/.ssh/id_rsa"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="ansible"' -o ConnectTimeout=60 -o ControlPath=/root/.ansible/cp/a35139d2ee '[lpdepmld2.uem.lan]'
<lpdepmld2.uem.lan> (0, 'sftp> put /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-105179U75Grh/tmp7Lwygf /home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1609256333.17-248021594072394/AnsiballZ_command.py\n', '')
<lpdepmld2.uem.lan> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: ansible
<lpdepmld2.uem.lan> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o 'IdentityFile="/home/ansible/.ssh/id_rsa"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="ansible"' -o ConnectTimeout=60 -o ControlPath=/root/.ansible/cp/a35139d2ee lpdepmld2.uem.lan '/bin/sh -c '"'"'chmod u+x /home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1609256333.17-248021594072394/ /home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1609256333.17-248021594072394/AnsiballZ_command.py && sleep 0'"'"''
<lpdepmld2.uem.lan> (0, '', '')
<lpdepmld2.uem.lan> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: ansible
<lpdepmld2.uem.lan> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o 'IdentityFile="/home/ansible/.ssh/id_rsa"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="ansible"' -o ConnectTimeout=60 -o ControlPath=/root/.ansible/cp/a35139d2ee -tt lpdepmld2.uem.lan '/bin/sh -c '"'"'/usr/bin/python /home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1609256333.17-248021594072394/AnsiballZ_command.py && sleep 0'"'"''
<lpdepmld2.uem.lan> (2, "/usr/bin/python: can't open file '/home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1609256333.17-248021594072394/AnsiballZ_command.py': [Errno 13] Permission denied\r\n", 'Shared connection to lpdepmld2.uem.lan closed.\r\n')
<lpdepmld2.uem.lan> Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Shared connection to lpdepmld2.uem.lan closed.
<lpdepmld2.uem.lan> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: ansible
<lpdepmld2.uem.lan> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o 'IdentityFile="/home/ansible/.ssh/id_rsa"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="ansible"' -o ConnectTimeout=60 -o ControlPath=/root/.ansible/cp/a35139d2ee lpdepmld2.uem.lan '/bin/sh -c '"'"'rm -f -r /home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1609256333.17-248021594072394/ > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'"'"''
<lpdepmld2.uem.lan> (0, '', '')
fatal: [lpdepmld2]: FAILED! => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"
    }, 
    "changed": false, 
    "module_stderr": "Shared connection to lpdepmld2.uem.lan closed.\r\n", 
    "module_stdout": "/usr/bin/python: can't open file '/home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1609256333.17-248021594072394/AnsiballZ_command.py': [Errno 13] Permission denied\r\n", 
    "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", 
    "rc": 2
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
lpdepmld2                  : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   

Tuesday 29 December 2020  16:38:54 +0100 (0:00:00.956)       0:00:01.063 ****** 
=============================================================================== 
shell ------------------------------------------------------------------- 0.96s
/etc/ansible/playbooks/test.yml:6 ---------------------------------------------
Playbook run took 0 days, 0 hours, 0 minutes, 1 seconds
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

And the `/var/log/secure` log on remote server at this moment :

```
Dec 29 16:38:53 lpdepmld2 sshd[64613]: Accepted publickey for ansible from 192.168.210.101 port 56150 ssh2: RSA SHA256:iZKO/9tfS6am2YAk8JRKDalRRwDNDubC5FAm+UUA9qw
Dec 29 16:38:53 lpdepmld2 sshd[64613]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user ansible by (uid=0)
```

In both case, I can see on the remote user i'm correctly connect with the private key and with "Ansible" user. So that's why I don't understand the Jenkins error result..

I'm already try to set something like this in ansible.cfg :

```
remote_tmp     = /tmp/.ansible-${USER}/tmp
```

But it doesn't works too.

Can somebody knows what's the problem ?

Thanks.

Comment: `can't open file '/home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1609248479.41-56317758605217/AnsiballZ_command.py': [Errno 13] Permission denied` => did you check that user has permissions to create/read those files ? Else did you try to relocate the ansible tmp dir in `ansible.cfg` ?

Comment: @Zeitounator Not having set the "remote_tmp" parameter in the Ansible configuration, this folder is created in the "/ home" directory of the connection user.

Here, I connect to the remote machine in "Ansible", so I necessarily have the permissions to my entire "/ home" directory.

Especially since by hand, without going through Jenkins, it works :-(

Comment: The ansible user in secondserver have full right in /home/ansible because it is his home directory : 
[ansible@secondserver ~]$ touch /home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/test
[ansible@secondserver ~]$ ll /home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ansible ansible 0 29 déc.  15:16 test
[ansible@secondserver ~]$

Comment: Sorry but your error message is saying the exact opposite... and in this case, I tend to trust machines much more than humans at first glance. Moreover, you are not showing your playbook so we have no clue what you are doing exactly (e.g. escalating privileges which might be the actual problem).

Comment: Don't add info in answers when it is not an answer. Edit your question. Don't add code/commands/output in screenshots: it is usually not readable, it impairs search engines ability to index the content and people trying to help you cannot copy/paste from it to reproduce the problem or search for solutions.

Comment: @Zeitounator I rephrased my first question with the elements provided in the comments. Is that ok for you now ?

Comment: This is indeed weird... You should watch the creation of the temporary file on the remote target while your run the playbook from jenkins to see if you notice anything unusual. I also notice that both runs are using the same ssh master session. You might want to start from scratch to see if it changes anything. But you bumped in something very unusual...

Comment: The one that works uses 'executable location = /bin/ansible-playbook`.  The one that fails has `executable location = /usr/bin/ansible-playbook`.  No idea whether that is relevant.